# Javascript Calculator Using Switch Statements

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, calculator

Here is what I have so far. I am having a hard time getting the calculator to clear after I enter in the calculation. Once I get my answer it show NAN in the box where you enter the numbers. Suggestions would be great!
Thank you

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function divide()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "/";
        }
        function add()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "+";
        }
        function num9()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "9";
        }
        function num8()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "8";
        }
        function num7()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "7";

        }
        function multiply()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "*";
        }
        function percent()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "%";
        }
        function num6()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "6";
        }
        function num5()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "5";
        }

        function num4()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "4";
        }


        function subtr()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "-";
        }

        function num3()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "3";
        }

        function num2()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "2";
        }

        function num1()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "1";
        }

        function numZero()
        {
            document.calculator.output.value += "0";
        }

function buildFormula()
{
var evalu= alert(eval(document.calculator.output.value)) + document.clear();
document.calculator.output.value= evalu;
}


</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="calculator">

<table border=0>
<tr>
    <td colspan=4><input type=text readonly=true name="output" size = 25></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   7   "  onClick="num7()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   8   " onClick="num8()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   9   " onClick="num9()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    /  " onClick="divide()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "     + " onClick="add()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   4   " onClick="num4()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   5 " onClick="num5()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   6  " onClick= "num6()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    *   " onClick= "multiply()"></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    %    " onClick="percent()"></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=button value = "   1   " onClick="num1()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   2   " onClick="num2()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   3   " onClick="num3()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "    -    " onClick="subtr()"></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "     =     " onClick="buildFormula()"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=5><input type=button value = "             0             "     onClick="numZero()"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: To make it work you would have to try something first. Your notes seem to walk you thru the process pretty well. Why not try to do what they say?

Comment: Thank you s but I am still having some problem with it clearing in my calculator. Would you be able to help me with this

Answer (score 0):

You should specify a doctype if you're using HTML and make sure the html is valid.

It's better not to mix your html with javascript so add event handlers with `addEventListener` in JavaScript

It's better to add the event listener to the container that contains the buttons instead of adding it to every button.

It's better to add script somewhere where it makes sense. Having the script in the head and trying to add event handlers to elements that don't exist yet doesn't make much sense. Adding extra script to compensate for that (body.onload) still isn't as good as just adding the script at the end of the content.

You still have to write the switch statement (if it is homework) to calculate the result but numbers are stored in calc.numbers and operators in calc.operators:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
 <title>My calc</title>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<form name="calculator">
<table  id="buttons">
<tr>
    <td colspan=4><div id="output"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   7   "  ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   8   " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   9   " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    /    " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "     +     " ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type=button value= "   4   " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   5   " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "   6   " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    *    " ></td>
    <td><input type=button value= "    %    " ></td>
</tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type=button value = "   1   " ></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   2   " ></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "   3   " ></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "    -    " ></td>
        <td><input type=button value = "     =     " ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td colspan=5><input type=button value = "             0             " ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>
var calc={
  curNum:[],
  numbers:[],
  operators:[],
  output:document.getElementById("output"),
  clickHandler:function(e){
    var ev=e||window.event;
    var nr=parseInt(ev.target.value);
    if(isNaN(nr)){
      calc.handleOperator(ev.target.value);
      return;
    }
    calc.curNum.push(nr);
    calc.output.innerHTML=calc.curNum.join("");
  },
  handleOperator:function(val){
    if(val==="     =     "){
      calc.calculateResult();
      return;
    }
    if(calc.curNum.length===0&&calc.numbers.length===0){
      return;
    }
    // when you press + and then % (replace + with %)
    if(calc.curNum.length===0&&calc.operators.length){
      calc.operators[calc.operators.length-1]=val;
    }else{
      calc.operators.push(val);
    }
    calc.numbers.push(parseInt(calc.curNum.join("")));
    // reset current number
    calc.curNum=[];
  },
  calculateResult:function(){
    //you could use switch here but it's complecated
    // to implement 3+2*6 so using eval instead
    // if for your homework you need to use switch then good luck
    // based on the above example you have to calculate 2*6 first
    // so you'll have to loop through the calc.operators a couple of times
    if(calc.curNum.length){
      calc.numbers.push(parseInt(calc.curNum.join("")));
    }
    var i=0,op,res=[];
    for(i=0;i<calc.numbers.length;i=i+1){
      op = ((i)===calc.operators.length)?"":calc.operators[i];
      res.push(calc.numbers[i]);
      res.push(op);
    }
    calc.numbers=[];
    calc.operators=[];
    console.log(res);
    calc.output.innerHTML=(eval(res.join("")));
    calc.curNum=[];
    calc.curNum.push(parseInt(calc.output.innerHTML));
  }
}
document.getElementById("buttons").addEventListener("click",calc.clickHandler);
</script>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. You are 100% right it is homework. I have tried to watch tutorials but when you are an online student and your professor never reply's back to any questions you may have it makes learning very difficult. Learning Java to this extent on my own in 5 weeks was not a good set up for the class. My next JavaScript experience WILL be face to face.

Comment: Thank you for the resources but I am still having some problem with it clearing in my calculator. Would you be able to help me with this?

Comment: @EllenHarris To clear the calculator you can set calc.curNum, calc.numbers, and calc.operators to [] and set the innerHTML of calc.output to ""